# Spark, how to send statement query to external database (neither write nor read query)

Tags: postgresql, apache-spark, pyspark, databricks

I have an AWS RDS with postgresql. And I have two tables there: `staging_test` and `test`. I want to do a MERGE into `test` by using the data on `staging_test`.

Both tables are only in the AWS RDS. I have not copied them on databricks metastore. So I was hoping to send the MERGE statement from databricks into the RDS, as if I would run it in pgadmin.

However, all I found is how to use spark to write a pyspark dataframe to the external database using JDBC, or how to send a SELECT query to the RDS and retrieve the result as a pyspark dataframe. This is what I have found:

- Writing: `df.write.format('jdbc').options(...<connection_parameters>...)`
- Reading query: `spark.read.format('jdbc').options(...<connection_and_query_parameters>...)`

But I have not found how to send a query that is not meant to either write data or fetch data. Just meant to execute something on the RDS. Like running a stored procedure, Grant privileges, MERGE, Create index on a column, etc...

For example, if I wanted to just run this `GRANT SELECT ON schema.table to some_user`, how can I send that "query" string to an external database using spark? That "query" neither writes nor reads data, it's just sending a statement for the RDS to execute.

I was hoping for something like SQLAlchemy but on pyspark, where you can send those types of "queries"/statements to your database

```
from sqlalchmey import create_engine

<Set variables USER/HOST/PASS/PORT/DB>

str_engine="postgresql://" + USER+ ":" + PASS+ "@" + HOST+ ":" + PORT+ "/" + DB
engine=create_engine(str_engine)
conn=engine.connect()

query='INSERT INTO some_table (number1,number2) VALUES (1,2)`
conn.execute(query_update)
```

Following that same sqlalchmey example, is there a way that using spark we can send that `INSERT INTO some_table (number1,number2) VALUES (1,2)` query to an external database (using JDBC/ODBC) ?

It doesn't necessarily have to be an `INSERT` query, it can be a GRANT, MERGE, CREATE INDEX, execute a stored procedure, etc... Or any other statement that is not meant to return a dataframe or use  a pyspark dataframe to write to a table.

Answer (score 0):

Spark is a data processing engine, it has connectors to read and write data. If you need to run commands like DDL, stored procedures, etc. you just use respective SDK - Pyspark is still Python, you can utilize any other library. So yes, just go with SQL Alchemy or Psycopg.

If you really wanted it, you could define a function that executes a DDL for you that can be invoked from a SELECT statement...

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION exec_ddl(ddl_text text) RETURNS void AS $$$
BEGIN
  EXECUTE ddl_text;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

SELECT exec_ddl('GRANT SELECT ON schema.table to some_user');
```

... and this in theory would allow you to run it from Spark like:

```scala
spark.read.format('jdbc')
  .options(...<connection_and_query_parameters>...)
  .option("dbtable", "(SELECT exec_ddl('GRANT ...')) as dummy")
  .load()
```

A really ugly workaround honestly.